# Sent Object as Parameter using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

So I want to sent parameter which like this:

I have a model like this:

```
class test{
  var id: String?
  var name: String?

}
```

Json i want :

```
[
{
 "id":"1",
 "name":"asda"

},
{

 "id":"2",
 "name":"asda"

}


]
```

and how to send that class as a parameter in alamofire ???

let parameter: [AnyObject] = listTest but it doesnt work :(

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604502/post-request-with-data-in-body-with-alamofire-4, In your case the data looks like an array of dictionary so you can try `parameter: [ [ String: String] ] `

Comment: its key:value but in my case only value without key :(

Comment: You can't send you object as such into Alamofire because it's not JSON valid. You may create a method for your class: `toDict()`, that will return a Dictionary [String:String], with `["id":id, "name":name]`, and then you create the array of theses.

Answer (score 1):

To send a single JSON object to your server using Alamofire, you just have to convert your object to a serializable dictionary. For example:

```
extension Test {
    func toDict() -> [String: String] {
        return ["id": id ?? "", "name": name ?? ""]
    }
}
```

And send it specifying the correct JSON encoding:

```
let parameters = test.toDict()
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

Sending an array of dictionaries instead of a dictionary is a little bit trickier. Code extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027253/469218):

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let values = tests.map { $0.toDict() }

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])

Alamofire.request(request)
```