# Swift Alamofire using POST request

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to a post request with a body in swift using Alamofire.

How to pass below parameter :

[ {"name":"online","value":false,"type":"checkbox"},{"name":"with_photo","value":true,"type":"checkbox"},{"name":"birthdate","value": {"lower":22,"upper":30}, "type":"range"} ]

Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your tried code. You can also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better construction of your question. It will help you get better help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST request with data in body with Alamofire 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604502/post-request-with-data-in-body-with-alamofire-4)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Going into the Alamofire documentation provide extensive detail into your problem with adding data to a post request. [See here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders)

To answer your question however, this code should do the trick.

```
let parameters =[{"name":"online","value":false,"type":"checkbox"},{"name":"with_photo","value":true,"type":"checkbox"},{"name":"birthdate","value":{"lower":22,"upper":30},"type":"range"}]

// All three of these calls are equivalent
AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters) // encoding defaults to `URLEncoding.default`
AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default)
AF.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder(destination: .methodDependent))
```

Comment: Do you have any error or debugging information? Likewise, have you tried to read through the documentation linked?

Comment: I have added same parameter but getting error

" '=' must have consistent whitespace on both sides
Closure expression is unused
Did you mean to use a 'do' statement?
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
Insert ';'
Expected expression. "

getting above error